# How To Find The Angle (in Degrees) of a Joystick on a Gamepad Controller?

Tags: math, geometry

I want to determine the absolute value in degrees of the joystick's position on a gamepad, using the x and y values.
I'm not good at math so I'm failing to find a simple answer to this question with example code on the internet, sorry if this a complete noob question !

I've tried `radiansToDegrees(atan(Joy2y/Joy2x));` and `radiansToDegrees(atan2(Joy2y, Joy2x));`

but here is what I get :

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: those numbers are likely very wrong.  they would usually be (if you want to start at the bottom as zero), going clockwise: 0° at the bottom then clockwise 90°, 180°, 270°.  note  that "360" would be "0" again.

Comment: @Fattie Exactly, that's what I would expect, but I get these very wrong numbers instead

Comment: atan2 function takes two arguments

Comment: thanks for pointing this out @MBo , it was a typo, i edited the question. Does that mean that atan2 should already be the solution ?

Comment: Usually the positive x-axis would be considered be 0 degrees; positive y-axis is 90 degrees; negative x-axis is 180 degrees; negative y-axis is 270 degrees.  I would suggest that you try atan2(y, x), knowing that the answer is in radians.